# Efficiently Referencing Variables / Storing Values in Class Variables

Tags: c#, class

So I'm making a taboo game with numerous instances of a class, but I'm not sure how to most efficiently keep track of which cards have already been played.

```
        TCard card;
    Random cardRand = new Random();
    int points;
    bool c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6;

    public Taboo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CardMethod()
    {
        cardNumber = cardRand.Next(1, 7);
        switch (cardNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                if ("c{0}", card.ID == false)
                {
                    card = new TCard("happy", "sad", "angry", "glad", 1);
                    break;
                }
                CardMethod();
                break;
```

You can see what I'm attempting to do with the "if" statement even though it doesn't compile. Is there something I can do there, or is there a better way I can store a value and check if the card is been played so that I can skip it?

Comment: No, our mind reading skills aren't that good. Please explain what you are trying to do, and why that is not working.

Comment: case 1:
                if ("c{0}", card.ID == false)

This code doesn't compile, but it reference the bool c1 in this case, so I can check whether or not this card has been played. So if the card has been played, this bool changes to "true" and the CardMethod() will repeat until it finds a card that hasn't been played.

Comment: *shuffle* the cards, put them in *stack*, *pop* them as needed.  the shoe will use itself up, research the emphasized words